# Estou-me nas tintas!? Quais tintas?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Parece-me que esta expressão não se usa no Brasil. Mas em Portugal [***estar-se nas tintas***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tinta) (para alguma coisa) significa não ter um mínimo de interesse, consideração ou respeito (por essa coisa), não querer saber (dessa coisa):

> «Mas eu acho que tu não estás a proceder bem.»
>   «Estou-me nas tintas (para o que tu achas).»

Mas que tintas são estas? Qual é a origem desta expressão?

Comment: Tem um equivalente brasileiro que também não faz sentido algum se levado ao pé da letra: *estou pouco me lixando*.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que *estar-se pouco lixando* não se usa cá, mas ainda assim consigo dar-lhe uma interpretação (que poderá não ter nada a ver com a origem). *Lixar* significa entre outras coisas *arreliar, chatear*. Portanto, *estou pouco me lixando*, *estou pouco me arreliando*, subentende-se *estou-me nada arreliando.*

Comment: Vai ser difícil. O [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/estou-me-nas-tintas/5559) também não sabe. Não é uma expressão nova — o Google books tem duas entradas do século XIX.

Comment: Serão as tintas uvas?

Comment: Também me veio à cabeça as uvas tintas, mas não consigo ver relação.

Comment: Além de "estou (pouco) me lixando" comentado por @bfavaretto   em ptBR temos também a forma chula "estou cagando para o que você acha", mais fácil de ser entendida literalmente.

Comment: @Centaurus É comum também em Portugal (vê comentários à resposta).

Comment: Outra expressão poderia ser "dar de ombros"? "- Ele deu de ombros para o que ela falava"

Comment: @AndréLyra Essa nós não temos em Portugal. Temos  é "encolher os ombros", que segundo o Aulete também é usada no Brasil e significa o mesmo que *dar de ombos*

Comment: @Centaurus ... e andando: *estou como os cavalos no desfile da Independência: cagando e andando, e todo mundo aplaudindo*...

Answer (score 2):

Deduzo que a lógica (da sua origem) seja mais simples do que parece: quem pinta fica normalmente cheio de tinta nas roupas, por isso alguém que «está nas tintas» não quer saber se outros notam ou não nos borrões de tinta espalhados pelo seu corpo.

Assumi isto devido a outras expressões equivalentes:

- «Estar a borrifar»: quem [borrifa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/borrifar) fica geralmente molhado, logo quem se «está a borrifar» não se importa que outros notem que está molhado.
- [«Estar a marimbar»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/andar-a-nora-andar-as-aranhas-estar-se-a-marimbar-leva-la-a-bicicleta/26351):

  > Entre os instrumentos de percussão existem as marimbas. Os tocadores de marimbas deliciam-se com a execução das suas obras musicais. «Estar a marimbar-se» significa estar tão encantado com as marimbas, que **não se dá qualquer valor ao que se passa em redor**.

Comment: Engenhoso, mas altamente especulativo. *Borrifar* poderá ser eufemismo para *mijar*: *tou-me a mijar para isso*

Comment: @Jacinto sim, apenas especulei com associações. Porém não associei a esse contexto de borrifos, mas sim, certamente! Nessa perspetiva, estar-se-á molhado devido a um líquido diferente... Btw, nice hat!

Comment: Não me parece que haja aí a implicação de a pessoa ficar molhada (ou cagada no *tou-me a cagar para*): acho que a coisa para que te borrifas é que ficaria molhada.  O ***me*** é capaz de ser do tipo de *me* em *olha-me só para isto*.

Comment: @Jacinto Ah, percebo! No entanto, se me estiver a marimbar para isso, posso estar tão encantado com as marimbas que não quero saber disso (e não necessariamente a «dar música» a/para algo:).

Comment: Uma interpretação ligeiramente diferente de *marimbar-me para uma coisa* seria a seguinte: eu desprezo de tal forma essa coisa que tenho até disposição para me pôr descontraidamente a tocar marimbas em vez de dar atenção à coisa. Não é ignorar a coisa por estar absorto com as marimbas. Agora isto é uma interpretação possível, não tou a dizer que isto esteve na origem da expressão. Marimbo também é um jogo de cartas.

Answer (score -2):

No Brasil tem uma expressão (chula) que pode explicar o "estou-me nas tintas". É o "estou cagando e andando". Quem caga e anda, não pode estar preocupado com nada. Está feliz da vida. O paralelo de "cagar" e "estar nas tintas" é obvio.
Abraços. Silvio

Comment: Sílvio, concordo que *estou-me nas tintas* significa o mesmo que *estou cagando e andando*. Em Portugal também se diz *cagando e andando* e *tou-me a cagar para (qualquer coisa)*. Mas não vejo como é que uma expressão explica a outra. Tenho até a ideia que quem ouvir pela primeira vez *estou-me nas tintas* não compreenderá o que significa mesmo que conheça o *cagando e andando*. Mas o voto negativo não é meu.